# calling an interval inside a class with a function

Tags: javascript

i'll try my best to describe what i'm trying to achieve, please correct me if there's a better way for doing so! :)

I just started practicing classes in javascript, and im trying to call an interval from a class function like this:

```
startRnd() {
  timer = setInterval(this.moveRnd, 1000);
}
```

as you can see in the full code below, i put in comment the functions because im trying to make this more 'dynamic', im trying to make it so when i create another bubble and click random, it will add it to the canvas and randomly move it in addition to the previous one created and moved.

so the result after 2 clicks will be 2 random bubbles moving around the canvas.
and when I hit stop it'll stop both of them.

edit:
when i call "startRnd", other functions that refered as "this" doesn't get recognized anymore and i cant figure out how it works :(

FULL CODE:

```js
let bubble;
let can = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
let cm = can.getContext('2d');
let timer;

// function startRnd() {
//     timer = setInterval(function(){bubble.moveRnd();}, 1000);
// }

// function stopRnd() {
//     clearInterval(timer);
// }

function setupBubble(tempX, tempY, tempR) {
  clearInterval(timer);
  if (tempX == undefined || tempY == undefined || tempR == undefined) {
    tempX = 0;
    tempY = 0;
    tempR = 0;
  }
  bubble = new Bubble(tempX, tempY, tempR);
  bubble.createBubble(bubble.x, bubble.y, bubble.r);
  console.log(bubble.x, bubble.y, bubble.r);
}

class Bubble {
  constructor(tempX, tempY, tempR) {
    this.x = tempX;
    this.y = tempY;
    this.r = tempR;
  }
  move(tempX, tempY) {
    this.x = tempX;
    this.y = tempY;
  }
  createBubble(tempX, tempY, tempR) {
    cm.beginPath();
    cm.arc(tempX, tempY, tempR, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    cm.stroke();
  }
  clrBubble() {
    cm.clearRect(0, 0, can.width, can.height);

  }
  moveRnd() {
    this.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (+can.width - this.r * 2) + this.r);
    this.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (+can.width - this.r * 2) + this.r);
    if (this.x < 0) {
      this.x = this.x + this.r;
    }
    if (this.y < 0) {
      this.y = this.y + this.r;
    }
    console.log(this.x, this.y);
    this.clrBubble();
    this.createBubble(this.x, this.y, this.r);
  }
  startRnd() {
    timer = setInterval(this.moveRnd, 1000);
  }

  stopRnd() {
    clearInterval(timer);
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body onload="setupBubble()">
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500" style="border: 1px solid"></canvas><br>
  <input type="text" id="_X" placeholder="X value" value="20"><br>
  <input type="text" id="_Y" placeholder="Y value" value="20"><br>
  <input type="text" id="_R" placeholder="Radius value" value="20">
  <button onclick="setupBubble(+_X.value, +_Y.value, +_R.value)">Create Bubble</button>
  <button onclick="bubble.clrBubble()">Reset</button>
  <button onclick="bubble.startRnd()">Random Movement</button>
  <button onclick="bubble.stopRnd()">Stop</button>
  <p id="_res">Results: </p>
  <script src="class_practice.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: your code does not work `Uncaught TypeError: this.clrBubble is not a function`

Comment: @Shahroozevsky
thats what im trying to figure out :(
i cant understand why it doesnt recognize other functions when calling it

i'll add it up to the thread

Comment: added to the thread !

Comment: Try `timer = setInterval(this.moveRnd.bind(this), 1000);`.  OR `timer = setInterval(() => this.moveRnd(), 1000);`.  Arrow functions maintain `this` but other functions do not.

Comment: @user2740650 it worked! sorry for bothering you again, can you explain to me how "arrow functions" works? its my first time using it!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE: Created a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-cohen-50nd2?file=/index.html) if anyone wanted to play around a bit more.**

I would like to suggest a more manageable architecture.

Your bubble creation shouldn't be the part of a `Bubble's` functionality.
Also, since your need multiple `Bubble`s, you need an owner to maintain all those bubbles, so you should create an array first.

Then you can have one function that keeps running on an interval and that function should be responsible for 2 things.

1. Clearing the canvas at the start of animation,
2. Asking all of your `Bubble`s to play themselves.

Each `Bubble` must be the owner of their process, i.e., they should have a `play` function which has 2 responsibilities,

1. Update the bubble's position (in your case this is random),
2. Draw the bubble at the updated location.

This kind of architecture let's you easily handle complex logic by dividing responsibilities.

Run the snippet and check it out.

Ask me any doubt you have with this. I understand it can be hard to wrap around at first, but once you get it, you will never go back.

```js
let bubbles = [];
let can = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
let cm = can.getContext('2d');
let playing = false;


function startRnd() {
  playing = true;
}

function stopRnd() {
  playing = false;
}

function onload() {
  setupBubble();
  setInterval(play, 500);
}

function play() {
  cm.clearRect(0, 0, can.width, can.height);

  bubbles.forEach(bubble => bubble.play());
}

function setupBubble(tempX, tempY, tempR) {
  bubbles.push(new Bubble(tempX || 0, tempY || 0, tempR || 0));
}

function reset() {
  bubbles = [];
}

class Bubble {

  constructor(tempX, tempY, tempR) {
    this.x = tempX;
    this.y = tempY;
    this.r = tempR;
  }

  play() {
    if (playing) this.update();

    this.draw();
  }

  update() {
    this.moveRnd();
  }

  draw() {
    cm.beginPath();
    cm.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    cm.closePath();
    cm.stroke();
  }

  moveRnd() {
    this.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (+can.width - this.r * 2) + this.r);
    this.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (+can.width - this.r * 2) + this.r);
    if (this.x < 0) {
      this.x = this.x + this.r;
    }
    if (this.y < 0) {
      this.y = this.y + this.r;
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body onload="onload()">
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500" style="border: 1px solid"></canvas><br>
  <input type="text" id="_X" placeholder="X value" value="20"><br>
  <input type="text" id="_Y" placeholder="Y value" value="20"><br>
  <input type="text" id="_R" placeholder="Radius value" value="20">
  <button onclick="setupBubble(+_X.value, +_Y.value, +_R.value)">Create Bubble</button>
  <button onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
  <button onclick="startRnd()">Random Movement</button>
  <button onclick="stopRnd()">Stop</button>
  <p id="_res">Results: </p>
  <script src="class_practice.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: this is exactly what i tried to achieve! i learnt a lot from reading it, i was far off in my way of thinking.

1 thing i didnt knew and i dont think i understand correctly

`bubbles.push(new Bubble(tempX || 0, tempY || 0, tempR || 0));`

why did you put var || 0? what does it do?

thank you for everything!!

Comment: Glad to have helped. This architecture helped a lot while game development.  The `||` means the `or` operator. `tempX || 0` means `if temp is present then use tempX or else use 0`. Your previous `if undefined` case works fine too. You dont need to use my `||` method. Just simplifies things.

Answer (score 1):

I see your problem: `this`.

In Javascript, the keyword `this` changes based on where a function is called from.

As you can see, when whatsThis is run from foo, `this == foo`.
When it is run from somewhere else, `this != foo`.

When you tell setInterval to run moveRnd, which uses the keyword `this` in it, this gets a different value.

Here are your possible solutions:

Arrow Function: `() => this.moveRnd()` This creates a new function in which this will always mean what it meant when it was created. This new function is what you give to setInterval.

Binding: `this.moveRnd().bind(this)` This creates a special function in which the value of this will always be equal to what is passed to `bind()`. In this case, you want it to be `this`.

Comment: this is the exact explanation i was looking for! thank you!!!